# Impacto de baja o modificación de un objeto SQL en la aplicación

Tags: base-de-datos, buenas-prácticas

Buen día estimados,

Mi consulta es muy básica y hace al comportamiento que debe adoptar la aplicación a la hora de dar de baja o modificar objetos de la base.

Supongamos que tengo una tabla 'Productos' donde cada elemento tiene una id única y que no debe repetirse. Por ejemplo:

1 - Placa de video
2 - Procesador
3 - Motherboard

Al mismo tiempo tengo otra tabla donde figuran las ventas de estos productos, que hacen referencia a las ids de la tabla 'Productos'.

**Baja de un producto**

Un usuario del sistema desea dar de baja el producto con id 2, porque ya no se vende más. Eliminar el registro directamente de la Tabla 'Productos' hará que la tabla de Ventas haga referencia a un id que ya no existe. El Reporte de Ventas no mostraría las ventas del producto con id 2. Por otra parte la eliminación debe ser efectiva porque el producto ya no se vende.

¿Como se resuleve esto? Mi idea es agregar una columna más en la tabla 'Productos' y si el producto es dado de baja agregar un flag que permita dejar de mostrar el producto donde no deba mostrarse y mostrarlo en los reportes donde si debe mostrarse. ¿Hay un método más estandarizado?

**Modificación**

Por otro lado la modificación. Si en lugar del usuario del sistema borrar el producto 2, modifica la descripción ingresando por ejemplo 'Monitor' en el producto con id 2, que antes era Procesador. Los reportes de transacciones anteriores se actualizarían con el nuevo producto reflejando ventas de monitores, cuando originalmente eran de procesadores.

Que metodo se utiliza para solucionar esto? Habia pensado que en el proceso de modifación en lugar de modificar la id del producto original, crear una nueva id para el producto modificado. Pero esto sería una agregación más que una modificación.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre esta clase de respuestas dependen del sistema, de como este construido, y de los requerimientos planteados por el cliente.

Sin embargo, como generalidades, vale lo siguiente:

- No se deben eliminar datos de las DB, salvo que los mismos ya no tengan ninguna clase de validez. En tu caso, aunque el producto se haya discontinuado, el mismo sigue siendo valido para reportes viejos, facturas y otras cosas, por lo cual no debe ser eliminado fisicamente. Si puede tener y corresponde que tenga una marca de producto dado de baja. Esta marca impide que se siga vendiendo, utilizando en altas de mercaderia y otras cosas.
- La modificacion de determinados campos debe estar sujeta a ciertas reglas propias de cada negocio. Aca es un tema un poco mas particulas segun cada caso, porque podria ser que datos importantes (como el nombre de un proveedor), no deberia modificarse. Pero que pasa si cargaron efectivamente mal el nombre??? si el proveedor cambia de nombre, se lo considera el mismo proveedor u otro?? Estas reglas de negocio son mucho mas particulares y cualquier respuesta es valida, basandose en el negocio. Asi que aca debes confirmar con el cliente como hay que resolverlo.
- En tu caso particular, que estas mostrando, y esta es mi opinion, deberias dejar modificar la descripcion, pero el uso y abuso del sistema ya corre por parte del cliente.